# I need help on display an AVL Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, avl-tree, display

```
data AVL t = Empty | Node t (AVL t) (AVL t) Int
                 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)


insertNode :: (Ord a) => a -> AVL a -> AVL a
insertNode x Empty = Node x Empty Empty 0
insertNode x (Node n left right balanceFactor)
    | x < n = let leftNode = insertNode x left
              in
               balanceTree (Node n leftNode right ((treeHeight leftNode) - (treeHeight right)))
    | otherwise = let rightNode = insertNode x right
                  in
                   balanceTree (Node n left rightNode ((treeHeight left) - (treeHeight rightNode)))

findNode :: AVL a -> a
findNode Empty = error "findNode from Empty"
findNode (Node a _ _ _) = a

findLeftNode :: AVL a -> AVL a
findLeftNode Empty = error "findLeftNode from Empty"
findLeftNode (Node _ left _ _) = left

findRightNode :: AVL a -> AVL a
findRightNode Empty = error "findRightNode from Empty"
findRightNode (Node _ _ right _) = right

findBalanceFactor :: AVL a -> Int
findBalanceFactor Empty = 0
findBalanceFactor (Node _ _ _ bf) = bf

treeHeight :: AVL a -> Int
treeHeight Empty = 0
treeHeight (Node _ left right _) = 1 + (max (treeHeight left) (treeHeight right))

balanceTree :: AVL a -> AVL a
balanceTree Empty = Empty
balanceTree (Node r Empty Empty bf) = Node r Empty Empty bf
balanceTree (Node r left right bf)
    | bf == -2 && rbf == -1 = let rl = (findLeftNode right)
                              in
                               (Node (findNode right)                                                               -- This is for the
                               (Node r left rl ((treeHeight left) - (treeHeight rl)))                               -- "right right" case
                               (findRightNode right)
                               ((1 + (max (treeHeight left) (treeHeight rl))) - (treeHeight (findRightNode right)))
                               )
    | bf == -2 && rbf == 1 = let rl = findLeftNode right
                                 rr = findRightNode right
                             in
                              (Node (findNode (rl))                                                                 -- This is for the
                              (Node r left (findLeftNode rl) ((treeHeight left) - (treeHeight (findLeftNode rl))))  -- "right left" case
                              (Node (findNode right) (findRightNode rl) rr ((treeHeight (findRightNode rl)) - (treeHeight rr)))
                              ((max (treeHeight left) (treeHeight (findLeftNode rl))) - (max (treeHeight (findRightNode rl)) (treeHeight rr)))
                              )
    | bf == 2 && lbf == 1 = let lr = findRightNode left
                            in
                             (Node (findNode left)                                                                  -- This is for the
                             (findLeftNode left)                                                                    -- "left left" case
                             (Node r lr right ((treeHeight lr) - (treeHeight right)))
                             ((treeHeight (findLeftNode left)) - (1 + (max (treeHeight lr) (treeHeight right))))
                             )
    | bf == 2 && lbf == -1 = let lr = findRightNode left
                                 ll = findLeftNode left
                             in
                              (Node (findNode lr)                                                                              -- This is for the
                              (Node (findNode left) ll (findLeftNode lr) ((treeHeight ll) - (treeHeight (findLeftNode lr))))   -- "left right" case
                              (Node r (findRightNode lr) right ((treeHeight (findRightNode lr)) - (treeHeight right)))
                              ((max (treeHeight ll) (treeHeight (findLeftNode lr))) - (max (treeHeight(findRightNode lr)) (treeHeight right)))
                              )
    | otherwise = (Node r left right bf)
    where rbf = findBalanceFactor right
          lbf = findBalanceFactor left
```

This is the current state of my implementation of an AVL Tree. The normal input is usually:

```
insertNode 4 (Node 2 (Node 1 Empty Empty 0) (Node 3 Empty Empty 0) 0)
```

which results in:

```
Node 2 (Node 1 Empty Empty 0) (Node 3 Empty (Node 4 Empty Empty 0) (-1)) (-1)
```

I want to now have a function to display an inputted tree in a neat fashion, for example, the tree directly above:

```
2
 1
  Empty
  Empty
 3
  Empty
  4
   Empty
   Empty
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this could be implemented? I wish for the Nodes to be displayed only, and once it reaches the end of a branch it prints "Empty". I've hit quite a brick wall and tried a few attempts with little success.

EDIT: Hi guys, thanks for the quick responses. Your suggestions do work, however, I would like an implementation of displaying the tree without the use of packages or libraries. Sorry for not clarifying this!

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is a pretty printer! I always use the “[pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty)” package on Hackage.

```
import Text.PrettyPrint
```

Your tree is a pretty simple structure, so I'm just going to define it all in one shot. There are many helpful combinators in `Text.PrettyPrint` though, so check them out! They're very easy to use in GHCi too, so when you don't understand the documentation, just give it a whirl.

```
prettyTree :: Show t => AVL t -> Doc
prettyTree Empty          = text "Empty"
prettyTree (Node t l r _) = text (show t)
                            $+$ nest 1 (prettyTree l)
                            $+$ nest 1 (prettyTree r)
```

`Doc` has a `Show` instance that you will probably be fine with, or you can use the more powerful styling functions.

```
λ let tree = Node 2 (Node 1 Empty Empty 0) (Node 3 Empty (Node 4 Empty Empty 0) (-1)) (-1)
λ prettyTree (tree :: AVL Int)
2
 1
  Empty
  Empty
 3
  Empty
  4
   Empty
   Empty
```

---

If you wanted to do this without any external dependencies, just crib the style but sub in your own shims for the combinators.

```
type Doc = [String]

text :: String -> Doc
text = pure

indent :: Doc -> Doc
indent = map (' ':)

vertical :: Doc -> Doc -> Doc
vertical = (++)

prettyTree :: Show t => AVL t -> Doc
prettyTree Empty          = text "Empty"
prettyTree (Node t l r _) = vertical (text (show t))
                                     (indent (vertical (prettyTree l)
                                                       (prettyTree r)))

render :: Doc -> String
render = concat
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! However I neglected to mention that I would like to have an implementation that wouldn't have to rely on the likes of Data.Tree (answer above) or PrettyPrint. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PremiumWall Updated. (Checked by brain, not by compiler.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the Data.Tree library by first converting your AVL tree to
a Data.Tree.Tree:

```
import qualified Data.Tree as T

data AVL t = Empty | Node t (AVL t) (AVL t) Int
                 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

toTree :: Show t => AVL t -> T.Tree String
toTree Empty = T.Node "Empty" [] 
toTree (Node t left right a)
  = T.Node (show t ++ " " ++ show a) [toTree left, toTree right]

avl = Node 2 (Node 1 Empty Empty 0) (Node 3 Empty (Node 4 Empty Empty 0) (-1)) (-1)

test = putStrLn $ T.drawTree (toTree avl)
```

Running `test` prints:

```
2 -1
|
+- 1 0
|  |
|  +- Empty
|  |
|  `- Empty
|
`- 3 -1
   |
   +- Empty
   |
   `- 4 0
      |
      +- Empty
      |
      `- Empty
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! Could you explain how the Data.Tree goes about doing this? And also, for this line

`test = putStrLn $ T.drawTree (toTree avl)`

what does the 'putStrLn $' do exactly?

Sorry if it's an obvious answer, as I'm used to just calling out the function and giving parameters like in the example inputs above

Comment: `putStrLn $ ...` is the same as `putStr (...)`